# How can I deploy a WPF application and database to a local network?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wpf

I've designed a HomeExpense Calculator using WPF. I want to deploy it on all of my roommates' laptop and store the database in each of them. Updates made in one laptop should reflect on others. We have a common wifi router. How do I proceed?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: you have to have some common base if you want all the applications to reflect changes to one another, either via database or a more conventional way, a server

Comment: I'm using Sql server.

Comment: If two people update at the same time, which database will be updated?